# sheet can not be dismissed after an alert is displayed

Tags: swiftui, alert, dismiss, swiftui-alert, swiftui-sheet

I’m trying to show alerts in a sheet in SwiftUI. I have Cancel and Save buttons on the sheet and  both of them are dismissed after the action is done.If there is an error on saving, an alert is pop upped. However, the sheet can not be dismissed after the alert is shown. Both save and cancel can not be dismissed after the alert dismiss is tapped. I can not figure out the reason. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Related code

```
        .navigationBarItems(
            leading:
                Button(action: {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }) {
                    Text("Cancel")
                        .foregroundColor(Color("OrangeColor"))
                        .font(.custom("Montserrat-Medium", size: 18))
                },
            trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    if selectedBook == nil {
                        errorInfo = AlertInfo(  id: .bookNotSelectedError,
                                                title: "Please choose a book",
                                                message: "")
                    }
                    if quote.isEmpty {
                        errorInfo = AlertInfo(  id: .quoteEmptyError,
                                                title: "Please choose a quote",
                                                message: "")
                    }
                    if let book = selectedBook {
                    // Save operations
                    }
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                })
                {
                    Text("Save")
                        .foregroundColor(Color("OrangeColor"))
                        .font(.custom("Montserrat-Medium", size: 18))
                }
                .alert(item: $errorInfo, content: { info in
                           Alert(title: Text(info.title),
                                 message: Text(info.message))
                       })
                
        )
```

Alert Info Struct

```
struct AlertInfo: Identifiable {
enum AlertType {
    case saveError
    case bookNotSelectedError
    case quoteEmptyError
    case totalPageError
    case currentPageError
}

let id: AlertType
let title: String
let message: String
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

Your SAVE Button checks for errors but then **always** calls dismiss() – so the Alert shows up, but vanishes immediately.
Also you have to check through the errors using ..else if...

This is how it should work:

```
           Button(action: {
                if selectedBook == nil {
                    errorInfo = AlertInfo(  id: .bookNotSelectedError,
                                            title: "Please choose a book",
                                            message: "")
                }
                else if quote.isEmpty {
                    errorInfo = AlertInfo(  id: .quoteEmptyError,
                                            title: "Please choose a quote",
                                            message: "")
                }
                else if let book = selectedBook {
                    // only call dismiss() after save was successful
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
                // NO dismiss here!
            })
        {
            Text("Save")
        }
```

Please also note that Alert and alert(item:content:) are deprecated.

Comment: Thank you very much. My logic was wrong, now it works 